# Can I bind a mac keyboard shortcut to enlarge the mouse cursor?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, macos-catalina

I want to trigger the temporary cursor enlargement that happens when you shake the mouse, but as a button press on my keyboard. I'm trying to make better use of my mousekeys in my keyboard config but can't find a way to get this onto a key.

I have a qmk configured keyboard, so macros are possible, but the editor doesn't allow mouse movement inside a macro. The only information i can find online is about how to enable the mouse shake is how to enable and disable the feature.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298550/85275 i don't think there's any other way except to shake it.